# How to limit size of user inputted string or dynamically allocate memory

Tags: c, string, user-input, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have this piece of code:

```
void main()
{
    char word[21]={0}; // changed from 20 to 21 because of '\0'.
    // do {
    scanf("%s", &word);
    // } while (strlen(niz)>20);  this line is useless because program crashes anyway
}
```

1. Question:
   The thing is I want to limit the number of characters user wants to input to 20. Sure I could reserve more memory for word[] but if I went over certain number the program would crash again. How do you get around this in C?
2. Question:
   Is there any way I can allocate needed memory for the string just after user enters it. For example if user enters string that has length of 999 can I allocate sizeof(string) * strlen(word) + 1 bytes of memory?

Note: if strlen() exceeds certain limit I want to prompt user to enter a new string again.

Comment: for 2) - not really. you have to allocate a buffer ahead-of-time. there won't be a magical area for the system to keep the input data until you can figure out how big it is. Once you call scanf, control is transferred to the input system until the user enters an eof/eol character.

Comment: the scanf format conversion parameters '%s' can have length and other details, depending on the conversion type, so you could say: scanf("%20s", &word);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the string length by using [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html):

```
fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
```

For second part:
Unfortunately, In C you can't allocate the exact amount of memory needed for the string entered. The reason is that you need to know the length of string before allocating memory for it and for this you must have to store that string in a buffer.

If you want to enter a string of any size and save memory at the same time, then use `realloc`.
Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = malloc(1);
    printf("Enter a string: \t"); // It can be of any length
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        c = getchar();
        s[i++] = c;
        s = realloc(s, i+1);
    }while(c != '\n' && c != EOF);

    s[i] = '\0';
    printf("Entered string: \t%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edited version is *much* better.

Comment: Sure you can...just not for the string *to be* entered. Once it's entered, you can allocated exactly what it needs and copy it over.

Comment: Isn't scanf("%20s", &word); more elegant solution than using fgets?

Comment: `scanf` usually do not read a full line of input. It stop reading the line if it find a white-space character (space, tab, newline ..) on the other hand `fgets` read full line and it is safer than that of `scanf`.

Comment: This approach enters an infinite loop on `EOF`.  Suggest using `fgetc()` rather than `scanf("%c", &c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of `scanf` support `m` modifier. For example in glibc>=2.7. They allocate necessary buffer for the user:

```
   char *p;
   int n = scanf("%ms", &p);
   if (n == 1) {
       printf("read: %s\n", p);
       free(p);
   } else {
       // error
   }
```

There is also older `a` modifier which does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Put a character constant in front of s in %s:

```
scanf("%20s", &word);
```

Your second question: in short No.  You need memory space to take the input.  A common solution however, to reduce allocations is do do something like:

```
char tmp[1000];
char *strptr;

scanf("%s", &temp);
strptr = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(tmp)+1));
```

but that will only save you space if you call this function 1000s of times.

Comment: Thanks! My program doesn't crash now and I can prompt user if he enters more than 20 chars. I also found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164000/how-to-dynamically-allocate-memory-space-for-a-string-and-get-that-string-from-u?rq=1

Comment: That answer is a good solution.  It's how I generally take user input without wasting allocated space.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the input by using fgets instead.

```
fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
```

if later need to extract things from the string use `sscanf`

Answer (score 0):

Use command line arguments..
main(int argc, char *argv[ ])

Here argc will tell you how many arguments are passed when you are giving executable.

argv will give you the data or string.. Just give it to a 'char *'.