# Copying array of characters into a text file

Tags: c, file, fwrite, dynamic-allocation

I want to write sentence(s) to a text file using `fwrite` function. So I have to have these as function arguments:

```
fwrite( const void *restrict buffer, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *restrict stream )
```

1. buffer  -   pointer to the first object in the array to be written
2. size    -   size of each object
3. count   -   the number of the objects to be written
4. stream  -   pointer to the output stream

As the [How to dynamically allocate memory space for a string and get that string from user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164000/how-to-dynamically-allocate-memory-space-for-a-string-and-get-that-string-from-u) said, it is a bad practice to waste memory. I read the answer and got an idea to write a code in my way.

My idea is :

1. to make an array of character and write to its elements
2. make that array bigger and bigger using `malloc` and `realloc`
3. Writing continues until it reach the `EOF`

Unfortunately I encounter a problem. Whenever I build and execute the code it gives me this error:

> has stopped working

Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t index=0,size=1;
    char ch;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("E:\\Textsample.txt","w");

    /////////////////Checking///////////////
    if(fptr==NULL)
        {
            free(fptr);
            puts("Error occured!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    /////////////////Checking///////////////

    char *sentence =(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)) ;
    puts("Plaese write :\n");

    while((ch=getchar()) != EOF)
        {
            sentence[index]=ch;
            index++;
            size++;
            realloc(sentence,size);

            /////////////////Checking///////////////
            if(sentence==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Error Occured!\n");
                    free(sentence);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            /////////////////Checking///////////////

        }

    //Copying sentnce(s) to the text file.
    fwrite(sentence,sizeof sentence[0],index,fptr);
    free(sentence);
    free(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: You don't need to free a NULL ptr in the Checking code..

Comment: "has stopped working"?  What?  Maybe run in a debugger and see which line it crashes on.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma- What if it fails to reallocate ?

Comment: @Ceeker in the first fopen call I meant

Comment: @HennoBrandsma- same goes to this.

Comment: @Ceeker, you check it is `NULL` so you are sure it is. No resources need to be freed then.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma- Got it! Thanks.

Comment: Also, at the end do `close(ptr)` as it is a `FILE *`. No free needed, it's handled by `fclose`

Comment: How do you end input?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma- Pressing 'ctrl+z' but it still gives me that error.

Comment: `getchar()` returns an `int` not a `char`, which is important to successfully detect `EOF`.

Comment: You might like to spend a few minutes reading this: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @alk- I had recalled that. But I can't cast it in while section.

Comment: Crl+Z puts the program in the background. To be sure of right sizes do `sentence[index]  =(ch & 0xff);`

Comment: No need to cast. Just do `int ch;` instead of `char ch`, or `int result; while ((result = getchar()) != EOF)
        { ch = result; ...`

Comment: `sentence[0]` is a `char`, so this `sizeof sentence[0]` evaluates to the size of a  `char`, which is `1`, always.

Comment: You might want to handle EOF separately too, before you get a newline..

Comment: @alk I do that.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `sentence = realloc(sentence, size)`, I think.

Also , it's more efficient to double the alloc-ed size, every time we need to. 
Then we can read as many again as we have read already, so we need fewer reallocations. So then `size` doubles (it is the size of the allocated buffer, while `index` keeps track of read characters.

So

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t index=0,size=1;
    int ch;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("./bla.txt","w");

    /////////////////Checking///////////////
    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occured!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /////////////////Checking///////////////

    char *sentence = malloc(size) ;
    puts("Please write, (close with return) :\n");

    while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
    {
            sentence[index]=(ch & 0xff);
            index++;;
            if (index >= size){
                    sentence = realloc(sentence,2*size);

                    /////////////////Checking///////////////
                    if(sentence==NULL)
                    {
                    fclose(fptr);
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error Occured!\n");
                    free(sentence);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }
                    /////////////////Checking///////////////
                    size *= 2; /* update size */
            }
    }

    //Copying sentence(s) to the text file.
    fwrite(sentence,1,index,fptr);
    free(sentence);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
```

}

which works fine on my system.

Comment: I did what you've mentioned but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to write stdin to a file you already have open. So why not cut out the malloc middle man?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("./bla.txt","w");

    /////////////////Checking///////////////
    if(fptr==NULL)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error occured!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    /////////////////Checking///////////////

    puts("Please write, (close with return) :\n");

    while((ch=getchar()) != '\n')
    {       
            fputc(ch, fptr);
    }
    //if you want the newline too 
    fputc('\n', fptr);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
```

}